# What would happen to a human in ordinary winter clothes who is tied to the Falcon 9 first stage during its ascent?

Tags: falcon-9, medical, first-stage, ascent

If there was an average-health-human tied to the Falcon 9's first stage during an ascent of the rocket into space, what would happen to them over the course of the flight in case they wore ordinary winter clothes (including a hood) and no oxygen mask, and what would happen in case they'd also wear a diluter demand oxygen mask but no spacesuit?

How would they feel at what point of the ascent? What would they feel? When might they pass out? When might they die? Certainly both would die soon after reaching the Armstrong limit the latest, but as mentioned before I wonder about the details and likelihoods of all that could happen to a human tied to the rocket.

Since according to the comments, the vibrations would already kill the human, let's assume they're attached to something that doesn't make the vibrations a problem. Something like a seat perhaps.

Comment: The vibrations might kill them in seconds. I hope nobody has tested that though

Comment: @Topcode Alright, then let's assume vibrations are no problem for the one who is tied to the stage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could one survive a ride into orbit outside a rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54159/could-one-survive-a-ride-into-orbit-outside-a-rocket)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Only in part, and only for the one with a spacesuit. My question is about the 1st stage, and therefore a suborbital flight with the additional question whether they could survive with a parachute, and two examples with no full-pressure suits on.

Comment: That is too many questions for one post. Suggest an edit to remove what is in the other question and narrow down to one scenario. We certainly can't know "how they would feel".

Comment: I think the answer is that the vibrations would probably kill the human. If you're handwaving the vibrations, that's a strange sort of rocket - it sounds like you have something more specific in mind.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I meant physically how they'd feel, not emotionally. I'll narrow the question down.

Comment: if you're choosing to ignore the acoustic/vibration environment, this is basically an aviation question

Comment: Might be better to work backwards thru the cause of death events. Let’s face it, at some point, you are going to die. If you survive everything else, you will asphyxiate. Shouldn’t be hard to determine the maximum elapsed time to when you lose consciousness and when you die of asphyxiation. So between engine ignition and the asphyxiation time, folks can propose the specific cause of death and expected time.

Comment: @AnthonyStevens Wouldn't the dude with the diluter demand mask survive until the Armstrong limit where his exterior liquids would boil away?